# \;WebDavRedirector and \;LanmanRedirector windows folder paths are local or remote

Tags: windows, filesystems

I am trying to figure out what happen when the system access the following folders:

- \;LanmanRedirector
- \;WebDavRedirector

are those local folder? or remote folders?
i need to figure out if the access is remote or local so i can fill the right IP address.

Comment: Those aren't folders. A mapped-drive (e.g. "Z:") is an NT SymbolicLink object that targets a redirector path such as "\Device\LanmanRedirector\;<drive letter>:<logon-session id>\<server>\<share>\<path>". Starting with Vista, "\Device\LanmanRedirector" is a SymbolicLink object that targets "\Device\Mup\;LanmanRedirector". The final resolved path is "\Device\Mup\<server>\<share>\<path>", so the local device is MUP (i.e. Multiple UNC Provider). Even if "<server>" is local (e.g. "localhost"), requests still go through the MUP device to the UNC provider (e.g. LanmanWorkstation).

Comment: @eryksun , is the <drive letter>:<loggin-session id> documented somewhere, or is it otherwise reliable (in a sense that it won't change in some future updates of Windows without any communication beforehand).? I'm asking since I need to extract <server>\<share> and want to check if a simple string processing approach is reliable.

Comment: @David, it's an undocumented implementation detail as far as I know. Call [`WNetGetConnectionW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnetwk/nf-winnetwk-wnetgetconnectionw) to query the remote path of a mapped drive.